# Visualize dynamic data using mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am following this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/) to visualize data on a map using mapbox. I use the following code:

```
<script> mapboxgl.accessToken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN; var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    zoom: 12,
    center: [-122.447303, 37.753574] });

map.on('load', function () {

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'population',
        'type': 'circle',
        'source': {
            type: 'vector',
            url: 'mapbox://examples.8fgz4egr'
        },
        'source-layer': 'sf2010',
        'paint': {
            // make circles larger as the user zooms from z12 to z22
            'circle-radius': {
                'base': 1.75,
                'stops': [[12, 2], [22, 180]]
            },
            // color circles by ethnicity, using data-driven styles
            'circle-color': {
                property: 'ethnicity',
                type: 'categorical',
                stops: [
                    ['White', '#fbb03b'],
                    ['Black', '#223b53'],
                    ['Hispanic', '#e55e5e'],
                    ['Asian', '#3bb2d0'],
                    ['Other', '#ccc']]
            }
        }
    }); }); </script>
```

My question is that I have a size-variable dataset, which is the result of user queries, and I would like to visualize my dataset. 
How to use mapbox to obtain this behavior?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is small enough, you simple load it all into the browser as a GeoJSON object, then display it with a `geojson` source. See [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/).

If the data changes, you simple update the source object with `.setData(newdata)`: [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-line/).

Comment: Hey, your link for setData(newdata) is dead, Can you please update the link ?

Comment: Hey this is the new link https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/sources/#geojsonsource#setdata

Comment: What would you recommend if the data is large and changes often?

Comment: PostGIS with ST_AsMVT.

Comment: Sounds like you have other questions you should ask...as questions.

Comment: Fair enough :) Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75740646/dynamically-showing-data-in-mapbox