# Dynamically showing data in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, geo

I have a large geo database of places of interest (POIs) and I am using MapboxGL to display it to the user. Based on the user input (filter and map location) I need to query the database and dynamically display the results to the user.

At the moment, I am using `map.on('load',...)` to add a source `map.addSource(sourceId, ..)`

Every time the user pans, zooms or filters the map I try to update the points on the map based on the data I receive from the query:

```js
const source = map.getSource(sourceId) as GeoJSONSource;
if (source) {
    source.setData({ type: 'FeatureCollection', features: features });
}
```

The load from the database is quick (and it is debounced) but it comes back with lots of points which results in a lag. This is because Mapbox computes every point each time `setData` is called which will result in a large CPU usage.

I tried to `debounce` the above method but since there might be a lot of points involved, there is still a big lag once the `setData` is called.

Note: I have two layers that cluster and display points. However, if I remove them the performance is comparable. They are are not the bottleneck and neither is the db query.

Is it possible to only append the data to the source rather than set it every time? Is there a better solution to dynamically visualise the points to the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding based on similar situations is that the bottleneck is actually that when you call `setData()`, the GeoJSON is inserted into the current style (which becomes an enormous piece of JSON), and there is a bunch of processing that that triggers. I could be wrong on this, though.

If the GeoJSON can be fetched by simple URL, you might try passing that URL to `setData()` instead of fetching the data then passing the data.

> Is it possible to only append the data to the source rather than set it every time?

Not within Mapbox GL JS. You can of course do that manually to reduce network traffic but you said that isn't the bottleneck.

> Is there a better solution to dynamically visualise the points to the user?

Dynamically generated vector tiles, such as from PostGIS with `ST_AsMVT`.

You could also consider loading an area larger than the viewpoint, and only repeating your fetch/update cycle when the pan exceeds that area.

You can also cache previous fetches, so you don't need to fetch/update if the user pans back over an area already loaded.